# Parse queries do not show most recent data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class loadMainViewController: UIViewController {

    //create new pfQuery - This is the bridge between our app and Parse: "trivia" is our class name on Parse
    let queryTrivia: PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"trivia")

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //retrieve data from parse query
        retrieveTrivia()  
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func retrieveTrivia() {

        //This CLOSURE gives access to all objects in "trivia" class using our queryTrivia Bridge
        queryTrivia.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if( error == nil ){

            print("error is nil")
        }
            var didLoad = true

            // Loop through the objects array
            for triviaObject in objects!{

                // Retrieve data for each object (key, question, ans2, ans3, correctAns)
                let triviaQuest : String? = (triviaObject as PFObject)["question"] as? String
                let triviaAns2 : String? = (triviaObject as PFObject)["ans2"] as? String
                let triviaAns3 : String? = (triviaObject as PFObject)["ans3"] as? String
                let triviaAns : String? = (triviaObject as PFObject)["correctAns"] as? String
                let triviaKey : Int? = (triviaObject as PFObject)["key"] as? Int

                //Check that items are not nil, and create trivia object, add to triviaQuestions Array
                if ( triviaKey != nil && triviaQuest != nil && triviaAns2 != nil &&  triviaAns3 != nil && triviaAns != nil){
                    let trivia = triviaQuestion(Key: triviaKey!, Question: triviaQuest!, Answer: triviaAns!, WrongAnswer:  triviaAns2!, WrongAnswer2:  triviaAns3!)
                    triviaQuestions.append(trivia) // append to the global array of trivia questions

                }else{
                    self.label1.text = "Network Error"
                    didLoad = false
                }   
            }

            for element in triviaQuestions{
                print(element.Key)
            }

            if (didLoad == true) {
                //perform segue to View Controller : Main menu
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finnishLoad", sender: self)
            }    
        }     
    }
}
```

My problem Lies when I query the data in the retrieveTrivia() method. The queries apeare to work with a few Problems. The data being saved in to the TriviaQuestion, TriviaAns, TriviaAns2, TriviaAns3 is old data that I have since changed using The parse website by simply clicking in the cell and editing each feild by hand. Furthermore I cannot seem to get the key field and it is always coming back as nil.

When I run this the triviaAns variable contains "Cow" but, online when looking at the data it says "Mozzarella."

Any idea as to why I would be receiving the wrong data after updating the fields and why the key field is coming back as nil?

Here is what the data looks like now 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwiJj.png)

Comment: First thing to do is check to see if error != nil. If it isn't then print it to see what went wrong. Second have you enabled parse local data store and pinned the result anywhere?

Comment: I added to the code to check if error is nil. It seems that error is nil. Yet I still get the old values. I am not sure how to enable parse local data store so I dont believe I pinned it else where.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one data class defined on Parse?

Comment: I 3 classes defined on parse. I have since deleted the other 2 and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your app from the simulator or device?  Have you checked your api keys; are you sure you are connecting to the right parse database?

Comment: Check the api key you are specifying in your app delegate to the one in your app control panel in parse

Comment: Okay you where correct @Paulw11 The application ID and Client key were wrong in my application. If you post an answer I will mark it as the correct answer. Thank you . Also if you could answer one more thing for me. Why would the application ID and Client key change from what they originally were?

Comment: If you create a new app or copy an existing app then you will get new keys.

Comment: I didn't create or copy a new app but the key did change. is it possible that it changes with the addition of new classes? @Paulw11

Comment: No. For it to be different you either need to change it in your app or in the parse control panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are connecting to the correct Parse app - Check the keys in the call to `setApplicationId:clientKey` in your App Delegate match those shown in your app's settings on Parse.com